# Change the list Items pogrammatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

currently i am using asp.net to create a list

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="formatOfReport" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" 
                  BorderColor="Black" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="formatOfReport_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                  style="width: 124px">
                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True">k</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>j</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I am new to c# and was wondering how I would set the list items programmatically as they are above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example from `page_load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       var item = new ListItem("k", "k");
       item.Selected = true;
       this.formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
       item  = new ListItem("j", "j")
       this.formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt make the first vbalue as selected

Comment: @TarangPatel: Thanks, corected. Mixed up the `Enabled` with the `Selected` property.